# Save creates a corrupted .mp4 file

Tags: python, animation, matplotlib

I have created an animation using matplotlib and I'm trying to save it to a file using the method described in this tutorial: http://matplotlib.org/1.4.2/examples/animation/basic_example_writer.html. Everything appears to work fine. The animation displays as expected in my pyplot figure and an .mp4 file is created as expected. However, when I try to open the file, windows media player crashes immediately. I am able to play other .mp4 files using WMP just fine and also when I inspect my file, I see that it contains all of my metadata as expected. I also tried running the example verbatim and the resulting file also had the same problem.

Version numbers for relevent packages are as follows:
Windows 7
Python        2.7.9
Matplotlib    1.4.2
ffmpeg        N-68625-G1728659

Here is an abridged version of my code. I didn't want to post the entire code because it is contained within something much larger that would only serve to confuse readers.

```
def simulate(self):
        fig = plt.figure()
        ims = []
        Writer = animation.writers['ffmpeg']
        writer = Writer(fps=15, metadata=dict(artist="me",title="test"))

        for i in range(looplen):

            #####code omitted: computing imdata

            im = plt.imshow(imdata)
            ims.append([im])

        anim = animation.ArtistAnimation(fig,ims,interval=3)
        anim.save('Simulation.mp4',writer=writer)
        plt.show()
        return anim
```

Comment: What versions of Windows, Python, matplotlib, and ffmepg were used?

Comment: Windows 7, Python 2.7.9, Matplotlib 1.4.2, ffmpeg N-68625-G1728659

Comment: Works for me with the exact same versions (all 64 bit). Try a different player, e.g. VLC. What is your shape of `imdata` and the value of `looplen`?

Comment: the images are 7x30 pixels and looplen is 90

Comment: Update: I also tried running the example verbatim and got the same result. I do have other .mp4 files on my computer that work fine, however.

Comment: What happens if you run `file` against it (or view the properties, either-or)?

Comment: As I mentioned, when I view properties, I can see all of my metadata as expected. Also, @cgohlke I installed VLC and am now able to play the video correctly. I'm now wondering if I send the video to someone else, will they be able to play it with WMP or any other player?